# Get onlyTrashed() does not exist in query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, soft-delete

I am trying to get trashed rows from table messages:

```php
public function trash() {
    return $this->onlyTrashed()
        ->where('user_id', '=', $this->_u)
        ->orWhere('receiver', '=', $this->_u)
        ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc')->get();
}
```

I get this error:

```php
Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::onlyTrashed does not exist.
```

I checked up Builder and SoftDeletes files for onlyTrashed method and it does not exist, how can I look up to trashed messages from message table?

The only way I think about is to create method that doesn't return messages where delete_at is not null and for trashed to return only those where it is not null. But I am still wondering why this doesn't work since it is in documentation at this url:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting

**MORE INFO**

Yes it is inside model and yes I added use SoftDeletes:

`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;` - on top

`use SoftDeletes;` after opening the class

Let me paste entire model here:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Messages extends Model
{

use SoftDeletes;

protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'subject', 'text', 'receiver'
];

public $_u;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function __construct() {
    $this->_u = auth()->user()->user_id; //or some id as string
}

public function trash() {
        return $this->onlyTrashed()
        ->where('user_id', '=', $this->_u)
        ->orWhere('receiver', '=', $this->_u)
        ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc')->get();
}

public static function trashed() {
        return self::onlyTrashed();
}
}
```

And controller has:

```php
public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

public function index($field = 'trash') {
    if ($field !== "new") {
        $messages = (new Msg)->$field();
        $user = auth()->user();
        return view('pages.messages', compact('messages', 'user'));
    }
    return view('pages.messages.new', compact('messages', 'user'));
}
```

I tried calling static as well and I tried doing it from **tinker** and still keep getting:

onlyTrashed() doesn not exist

Comment: Where did you put this function? in your model?

Comment: Yes, inside Messages model

Comment: Is this in your model? As well have you added the 'use SoftDeletes' in your model?

Comment: Yes  it is inside model and yes I added use SoftDeletes:

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes; - on  top
use SoftDeletes; after opening the class

Comment: Please show the entire code for your model. And how do you call this function?

Comment: Try replaceing $this with Self::

Comment: How are you calling the `trash()` method?

Comment: Changing it to self:: doesn't work as well, I am calling trash() from controller by:

`$messages = (new Messages)->trash();`

Comment: @Jerodev thats entire model it has protected `$dates = ['deleted_at']; $fillable,` and this method. And Messages controller just calls it like from comment before this one.

Comment: Could you please update your question so it shows all relevant code of your model? Missing $dates is somewhat important in this question aswell.

Comment: I added everything :D

Comment: @Jerodev I added my answer which I found, on the end is a question do you maybe know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call the parent constructor:

```php
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_u = auth()->user()->user_id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to define the `trash` method static:

```
public static function trash() {
    return self::onlyTrashed()
        ->where('user_id', '=', $this->_u)
        ->orWhere('receiver', '=', $this->_u)
        ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc')->get();
}
```

Then call this function by:

```
$messages = Messages::trash();
```

Comment: I did try this and still getting the same error :'(

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```php
# YourModelController.php
    /**
     * Show only trashed 
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function trashed()
    {
...
        $trashed = YourModel::onlyTrashed()->get();
...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have  researched a little further and I got this:

From https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent.html

I should have

> SoftDeletesTrait

but I have

> SoftDeletes

. In `softdeletestrait` we have `onlyTrashed` method but in `SoftDeletes` we do not.

So I copied that method from this page:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7d9e7068c49f945385673014d4cba4de28accd5e/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletingTrait.php#L119

And added it to `SoftDeletes` class, now it works like it should. I haven't find why it doesn't exist inside `SoftDeletes` class so if anyone find out let us know!